# Android paring with Bluetooth LE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, btle

I am experimenting with Bluetooth (Low Energy, or 4.0 specifically) connection between an Android phone and Android Wear smartwatch. In my case I am using a Samsung Galaxy S6 and Moto 360 (first gen), which both support Bluetooth LE.

I assumed that Bluetooth devices should prefer using the latest protocols. Even though both devices support classic BT and BTLE, they "should" connect over BTLE. However upon observing the data collected with Ubertooth One (http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/hardware/one/), I found this was not the case. Apparently I am getting ADV_IND broadcast packets from Moto 360 before paring, and once clicking on the phone to pair with the watch, the broadcast just halts, and no CONNECT_REQ or any further data packets can be observed.

As Ubertooth cannot see classic BT packets, I am wondering if it's because the smartwatch broadcasts on both the classic BT and BTLE channels, and the phone simply connects over classic BT?

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed that Bluetooth devices should prefer using the latest
>   protocols. Even though both devices support classic BT and BTLE, they
>   "should" connect over BTLE.

Did you ever read the core spec? but I remember they should connect over BR/EDR in this case. Sorry I do not have core spec in hand now I would post the volume/section later.

> As Ubertooth cannot see classic BT packets, I am wondering if it's
>   because the smartwatch broadcasts on both the classic BT and BTLE
>   channels, and the phone simply connects over classic BT?

There was one AD Type named "BR/EDR Not Supported or not" can show whether this device is only LE device or BR/EDR/LE supported. I am not sure what's your AD type sniffer but you may check this byte.
And smart watch can not broadcast over BR/EDR channels.

Comment: I would like to know specifically where in the core spec?

Comment: sorry I was too busy this days but I will come back to you when I found the volume/section later. Wait few days please.

Comment: Legend has it, Guo is still looking for the section in the core spec.

Comment: You're killing me :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the smartwatch announced in its advertisement that it support both LE & BR\EDR mode， the default action to pair with this device in android bluetooth stack is to page & connect，and that is to pair in BR\EDR mode, not LE mode.